# Setting up python on external HDD (on MacOS)

Tags: python, macos

I don't have access to current portable python solutions, and I'd like to put a bare bone python and manually add libs on an external HDD using a Mac.

I went to [python.org](http://python.org) but the `.pkg` file for Mac automatically installs python locally. I am wondering if there is a solution to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.pkg` installer clearly gives the option `Change Install Location...`:

[image]

> Try clicking the button and selecting the external drive.

Comment: Excellent! I was clearly wrong. If I were to install it after changing install location, would my `PATH` include python on my external drive (which I don't want it doing)?

Comment: Yes, it will unless you select `Customize` then deselect `Shell Profile Updater` and also `Install or upgrade pip`. I would recommend you deselect everything just to be sure nothing messes with your local Python.

Comment: If you don't have an OS installed on the external drive then the installer might not install everything correctly, as I personally have not tried this method. Generally Python expects certain directories to be present such as `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local`, etc. and without those you might run into problems. It might be better to use use `virtualenv` and download the source tarball and then compile and build it yourself. If you do decide to try the `.pkg` route then maybe post back here with the result or any issues.

Comment: @I'L'I For my installation, I definitely do not have  `Change Install Location` option. The button is no where to be found. I am running OSX 10.8.5 on an Admin account, but I don't think this would make a difference.

Comment: Are you downloading: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1-macosx10.6.pkg? The option should be on the third screen the installer presents... and does the external have an os on it? If not then the installer option won't work.

Comment: If you need instructions on how to install Python 3.6 into a self-contained `virtualenv` instead (which is what I definitely recommend), then let me know and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @l'L'l, you are right. the .pkg doesn't even allow to install onto a disk that doesn't contain macOS on there these days.